# Guarantee that GC will not affect the code

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, extension-methods

I have this extension method to disable a timer after a given interval. Is there a guarantee  that GC won't destroy the disableTimer variable (which is local variable in this method)? or is there a justification why this code will work in an hour from now.

```
timer.DisableAfter(1.Hours()) :

    public static void DisableAfter(this Timer timer, TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        var disableTimer = new Timer(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds)
            {
                AutoReset = false,
            };

        disableTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                timer.Stop();
                disableTimer.Stop();
            };
        disableTimer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: disableTimer will probably be long gone before you reach the 1 hour interval. You can't rely on it, not even a second after the method completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no garauntee it'll be garbage collected or not, but if you don't keep a reference to the timer it's certainly qualifies for collection.

See this MSDN page for Timer, go down to the first example source block, read the text above and obviously the source block itself... it's actually all about Timer's being garbage collected.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have another suggestion. It is simpler as it does not involve another Timer.
When you register a handler on the Elapsed method, wrap it with another handler that will hold the last time the timer fired. When the timer elapses, you first check whether an hour has passed and if so- you suppress the current execution and cancel the timer.

You have access to the timer object itself via the source parameter of the Elapsed delegate.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I got your idea fully - I'll try to implement it ;)